# Two set Intervals makes infinite loop

Tags: javascript, canvas, dom-events

I'm making a simple game, and I want to move 2 objects(two images of a cup) with `setInterval`.
After all of the function calls it will draw the picture into another place, makes it look like it's moving. If I use `setInterval` only once, there is no problem, but if I use it twice, it goes into an infinite loop. Could you please help me, why is it doing this?

```
window.onload = main;
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

function main(){
    backGround.src = "pic1";
    backGround.onload = function(){
        ballImg.src = "pic2";
        ballImg.onload = function (){
            cupImg.src = "pic3";
            cupImg.onload = function(){

                startGame();

            };
        };
    };
}

function startGame(){
    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    context.drawImage(backGround, 0, 0, w, h);
    context.fillText("START!",50,50);
    canvas.addEventListener('click',jonas, false);
}

    function jonas(){
    timer = setInterval(move_1_2, timeStep); //there is no problem if i use it once, but I would like to do it more time
    timer = setInterval(move_1_2, timeStep); //If use it like this, it goes into an infinite loop

}

function move_1_2 () {

    posX =((posX2-posX1)/density)*i;
    bposX =(bposX2-bposX1)/density*i;
    context.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
    context.drawImage(backGround, 0, 0, w, h);
    context.drawImage(cupImg, posX1 + posX, posY, cupw, cuph); //I draw 3 cups, the two at the sides are moving
    context.drawImage(cupImg, posX3, posY, cupw, cuph);
    context.drawImage(cupImg, posX2 - posX, posY, cupw, cuph);

    if (++i == density){
        i = 0;
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
}
```

Comment: You've overridden timer. Consequently, the clearInterval is only clearing the second setInterval. Either clear the first setInterval first, or use a different variable name.

Comment: how can i clear the frist setInterval first? I thought that when i first use the setInterval, that will clear itself, because it's in the move_1_2, and THEN it comes to the second setInterval.

Answer (score 0):

Use two different timers:

```
timerA = setInterval(move_1_2, timeStep);
timerB = setInterval(move_1_2, timeStep);
```

It's probably happening because you are not clearing "timer" before initiating it a second time

Comment: And how should i use clearInterval, if i dont't know, what was the name of my timerId? (in move_1_2 function i don't know that which is my id).

Comment: Now it only moves once, but i used setInterval twices, because i want to move it twice.

Comment: You need to call the second timer from the first one.

Comment: @user3115593 I don't think you understand set interval. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval